# About eigenvalues of probability matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

I am reading Lemma $5.3$ in page $7$ of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.11491.pdf). For the purposes of this question, I think it suffices to know $L,R$ are transition probability matrices i.e. their row sums are equal to $1$. The precise definitions of $L,R$ are in the paper.

1. I don't understand why: If $x$ is any vector orthogonal to the vector of all $1'$s and if $\lambda_2$ is the second largest eigenvalue of $R$, then

> $x^TRx \leq \lambda_2\|x\|^2$

If $x$ is the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_2$, then I know that $Rx=\lambda_2x\implies x^TRx=\lambda_2\|x\|^2$ but not sure why the above is true?

2. Below equation $(5.3)$, we have a statement: If $x$ is any vector orthogonal to the vector of all $1'$s (denoted by $1$), then stochasticity of $L$ implies that

> $1^T(L^T)^2x = 1^Tx=0$

I didn't understand why $(L^T)^2x=x$? Since $L$ is a stochastic/probability matrix, $L^T,(L^T)^2$ are stochastic/probability matrices but I'm not sure why that implies the above? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your first question is given in Corollary 5.2, as the paper states.
Because $R$ is symmetric, it has an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors. The largest eigenvalue is $\lambda_1 := 1$ with multiplicity $1$, and the corresponding eigenvector $v_1$ is the vector of all $1$s. Therefore, any $x$ orthogonal to the all $1$s vector is a linear combination of the other eigenvectors $v_2, \ldots, v_n$ of $R$, e.g. $x=c_2 v_2 + \cdots + c_n v_n$ and you can check that
$$x^\top R x = c_2^2 \lambda_2 + \cdots + c_n^2 \lambda_n \ge (c_2^2 + \cdots + c_n^2) \lambda_2 = \lambda_2 \|x\|^2.$$

---

For your second question, it is not that $(L^\top)^2 x = x$, but rather that $1^\top (L^\top)^2 = 1^\top$, or equivalently, $L^2 1 = 1$. Just use the fact that the rows of $L$ sum to $1$.